How do I correctly code sign using a certificate stored in Azure Key Vault with the trust chain included?
Our CA, GlobalSign has issued a code signing certificate meant for an HSM. I created a Premium licensed Key Vault in Azure since the basic doesn't support HSM. I then generated a certificate in the Key Vault using the following Issuance Policy:

Type of Certificate Authority (CA): Certificate issued by a
non-integrated CA
Subject: C=US, L=Doeville, O=JohnDoe, CN=JohnDoe,
E=johndoe@doe.com
DNS Names: 0 DNS names
Validity Period (in months): 24
Content Type: PKCS#12
Enabled: Yes

Advanced Policy Configuration

Extended Key Usages (EKUs): 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3
X.509 Key Usage Flags: Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
Reuse Key on Renewal?: No
Exportable Private Key?: No
Key Type: RSA-HSM
Key Size: 4096
Enable Certificate Transparency?: Yes
Certificate Type: {Empty}

Once it was instanced in the key vault, I clicked on Certificate Operation and downloaded the CSR.
I followed the download link provided by Global Sign and copied and pasted the CSR. After the certificates had been generated, I got a page where I could download the Digital certificate and 2 intermediate certificates. The file names were: OS123456789.cer, intermediate1.cer and intermediate2.cer
I then went back to the Azure Key Vault and click on "Merge signed request" I then picked the OS123456789.cer file, and it was successful.
I then started getting to work on using jarsigner to sign my jars.
I downloaded azure-security-keyvault-jca-2.8.1.jar and placed it in the %JAVA_HOME&/jre/lib/ext
The jarsigner command I use is this:
jarsigner -keystore NONE  -storetype AzureKeyVault -verbose  -storepass "" -tsa http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 -providerName AzureKeyVault -providerClass com.azure.security.keyvault.jca.KeyVaultJcaProvider -J"-Dazure.keyvault.uri=$KEYVAULT_URL" -J"-Dazure.keyvault.tenant-id=$TENANT" -J"-Dazure.keyvault.client-id=$CLIENT_ID" -J"-Dazure.keyvault.client-secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" -signedjar "signed.jar" "unsigned.jar" $CERT_ALIAS

The signing output looks like this:
updating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
adding: META-INF/GLOBALSI.SF
requesting a signature timestamp
TSA location: http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1
adding: META-INF/GLOBALSI.RSA
A BUNCH OF FILES
signing: clientlogging.properties
adding: JNLP-INF/
signing: JNLP-INF/APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP
>>> Signer
X.509, EMAILADDRESS=johndoe@doe.com, CN=JohnDoe, O=JohnDoe, L=DoeVille, C=US
[trusted certificate]
>>> TSA
X.509, CN=Globalsign TSA for CodeSign1 - R6 - 202311, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
[certificate is valid from 07/11/23 18:13 to 09/12/34 18:13]
X.509, CN=GlobalSign Timestamping CA - SHA384 - G4, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
[certificate is valid from 20/06/18 02:00 to 10/12/34 01:00]
X.509, CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R6
[trusted certificate]

jar signed.

The timestamp will expire on 2034-12-09.

It looks good so far, I think.
However, when I run:
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs signed.jar

I get the following output:
s 291951 Tue Sep 24 12:09:10 CEST 2024 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

>>> Signer
X.509, EMAILADDRESS=johndoe@doe.com, CN=JohnDoe, O=JohnDoe, L=DoeVille, C=US
[certificate is valid from 20/09/24 16:00 to 03/09/27 14:19]
[Invalid certificate chain: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
>>> TSA
X.509, CN=Globalsign TSA for CodeSign1 - R6 - 202311, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
[certificate is valid from 07/11/23 18:13 to 09/12/34 18:13]
X.509, CN=GlobalSign Timestamping CA - SHA384 - G4, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
[certificate is valid from 20/06/18 02:00 to 10/12/34 01:00]
X.509, CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R6
[trusted certificate]

292002 Tue Sep 24 12:09:12 CEST 2024 META-INF/GLOBALSI.SF
8401 Tue Sep 24 12:09:12 CEST 2024 META-INF/GLOBALSI.RSA
0 Tue Sep 10 16:47:38 CEST 2024 META-INF/
    
A BUNCH OF FILES

sm 1111 Tue Sep 10 16:47:36 CEST 2024 JNLP-INF/APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP
[entry was signed on 24/09/24 12:09]
>>> Signer
X.509, EMAILADDRESS=johndoe@doe.com, CN=JohnDoe, O=JohnDoe, L=DoeVille, C=US
[certificate is valid from 20/09/24 16:00 to 03/09/27 14:19]
[Invalid certificate chain: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
>>> TSA
X.509, CN=Globalsign TSA for CodeSign1 - R6 - 202311, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
[certificate is valid from 07/11/23 18:13 to 09/12/34 18:13]
X.509, CN=GlobalSign Timestamping CA - SHA384 - G4, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
[certificate is valid from 20/06/18 02:00 to 10/12/34 01:00]
X.509, CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R6
[trusted certificate]

s = signature was verified 
m = entry is listed in manifest
k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

Signed by "EMAILADDRESS=johndoe@doe.com, CN=JohnDoe, O=JohnDoe, L=DoeVille, C=US"
Digest algorithm: SHA-256
Signature algorithm: SHA256withRSA, 4096-bit key
Timestamped by "CN=Globalsign TSA for CodeSign1 - R6 - 202311, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE" on Tue Sep 24 10:09:12 UTC 2024
Timestamp digest algorithm: SHA-256
Timestamp signature algorithm: SHA256withSHA256withRSA, 3072-bit key

jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is invalid. Reason: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

The signer certificate will expire on 2027-09-03.
The timestamp will expire on 2034-12-09.

The verification fails with the following warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is invalid. Reason: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

As far as I understand, this occurs because it is unable to determine a chain of trust to the CA.
I then used keytool to import the intermediate certificates into my local keystore located under my home directory. I then signed the jar files again and this time jarsigner was able to verify the jar file without any warnings.
However, when I then deploy the java application and the users download the jnlp file and attempt to install the java application, they get a warning popup saying that the signed application is not trusted.
We are using java 8. Tried both the latest Amazon Corretto and Oracles
My questions are:

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?
Is it possible to include the intermediate certs when merging the signed request, and will that solve the issue?

Thanks for any assistance you can be provided.

I was able to figure it out.
You need to provide the certificate trust chain as a pem file to jarsigner via the -certchain option.
This is the correct command:
jarsigner -certchain trustchain.pem -keystore NONE  -storetype AzureKeyVault -verbose  -storepass "" -tsa http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 -providerName AzureKeyVault -providerClass com.azure.security.keyvault.jca.KeyVaultJcaProvider -J"-Dazure.keyvault.uri=$KEYVAULT_URL" -J"-Dazure.keyvault.tenant-id=$TENANT" -J"-Dazure.keyvault.client-id=$CLIENT_ID" -J"-Dazure.keyvault.client-secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" -signedjar "signed.jar" "unsigned.jar" $CERT_ALIAS

To create the pem file you need to concatenate the code signing certificate with the intermediate certificates. The order is important:
cat codesigner.cer, intermediate1.cer, intermediate.cer > bundle.pem

You can also use a text editor to combine the certificates.
You will know it works when you run jarsigner with the -verbose option and see the complete trust chain:
>>> Signer
X.509, EMAILADDRESS=johndoe@doe.com, CN=JohnDoe, O=JohnDoe, L=DoeVille, C=US
[certificate is valid from 20/09/24 16:00 to 03/09/27 14:19] 
X.509, CN=GlobalSign Code Signing Root R45, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
[trusted certificate]
X.509, CN=GlobalSign GCC R45 CodeSigning CA 2020, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
[trusted certificate]

